# select (click) labels in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, sld

I have the following style for an OpenLayers vector layer.

Color and Name come from Geoserver/PostGIS.

I red that setting `labelSelect` to `true`, user can also click the label, not only the point and fire an event such as `featureclick`. But no reaction. Clicking the point works, clicking the label does not. For my case, the following code is for points, lines and polys. What am I missing?

Thanks

```
var style_d = new OpenLayers.Style({
'fillColor': '${p_color}',
'fillOpacity': 0.8,
'fontColor': 'black',
'pointRadius': 12,
'fontWeight':'bold',
'strokeColor': 'black',
'strokeWidth': 1,
'fontFamily': 'Arial',
'fontSize': 15,
'label': '${p_name}',
'labelAlign': 'tc',
'labelOutlineColor':'white',
'labelOutlineWidth':3,
'labelOutlineOpacity':0,
'labelSelect': true,
'labelXOffset': 4,
'labelYOffset':4});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to place that code where you initialize your vector layer:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Valori", {
    [...]
    eventListeners:{
        'featureselected':function(evt){                
            //whatever you want
        },
        'featureunselected':function(evt){
                            //whatever you want
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```